# Can sexual orientation change in teen years?

Tags: sexuality

Can Sexual orientation change in teen years as teenagers go through lots of challenges.

And can a heterosexual teen become a homosexual teen.

Comment: https://www-marketwatch-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.marketwatch.com/amp/story/new-study-of-12000-people-says-sexuality-changes-from-adolescence-into-adulthood-2019-05-03?amp_js_v=a6&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQHKAFQArABIA%3D%3D#aoh=16167789732469&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=Source%C2%A0%3A%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.marketwatch.com%2Fstory%2Fnew-study-of-12000-people-says-sexuality-changes-from-adolescence-into-adulthood-2019-05-03   Yes sexual orientation can change even after your teens.

Comment: @Doliprane OK, but can a man who is heterosexual change into pure homosexual(not bisexual) . Even if he like to think about woman.

Comment: I think this question is very much opinion-based. The reason being that there are incidents where there are those who are aware they are Gay but choose to identify as heterosexual due to stigma within their social circle whether it is caused by religious faith or something else prejudicial. There are also those who are Bisexual but don't want to be for the same reason,  **or don't even know and identify it**. This later can change for various reasons. There are those who believe you are born with your sexual orientation, and there are those who think environmental factors cause changes.

Comment: @ChrisRogers just asking is it possible for a man who is heterosexual change into pure homosexual(not bisexual) . Even if he like to think about woman. Can you tell in the comments it self

Comment: @DarkKnight my **opinion based on my knowledge** is that you are born into an orientation and you can either accept it or try to deny it. A Gay man who is forced by their social circle to be heterosexual could try and act heterosexual and wish to be attracted to women but try as they may, they cannot be truly attracted to them

Comment: @ChrisRogers will it change in teen years.

Comment: @DarkKnight aren't three of your posts basically asking the same thing? I just went through a few of your questions and well, they could very well be answered as a single one with a few subparts

Comment: @RaghavendraSingh no, one is about hocd, one is about teen years and one is about sexual fluidity.